# tensorflow pseudo inverse doesn't work for complex matrices!

Tags: machine-learning, python, tensorflow, numpy, matrix

The Tensorflow documentation [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/linalg/pinv) says that:

> tf.linalg.pinv is ''analogous to numpy.linalg.pinv. It differs only in
>   default value of rcond''.
>
> However, tf.linalg.pinv requires the matrix to be float type while
>   np.linalg.pinv could be used with complex matrices.

I was wondering why they would only create it for float types and if there is a straightforward way to modify `tf.linalg.pinv` to be used with complex matrices.

Answer (score 0):

I just faced the same situation. If you need to explicitly build the inverse, check this paper:

https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/f278/b548b5121fd0d09c2e589439b97fad16ece3.pdf

In particular, given a Matrix M that you need to invert, you can just do:

```
    A = tf.math.real(M)
    C = tf.math.imag(M)

    r0  = tf.linalg.pinv(A) @ C
    y11 = tf.linalg.pinv(C @ r0 + A)
    y10 = -r0 @ y11

    M_inverse = tf.cast(tf.complex(y11,y10), dtype = M.dtype)
```

The complexity is a bit higher than the pure-complex implementation, but so far it has proven to be pretty stable for me.

(just copying my answer from your other post: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60025950/tensorflow-pseudo-inverse-doesnt-work-for-complex-matrices/60128892#60128892)